# Prepared Statements... What am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update some code and update my coding skills at the same time. After looking at prepared statements on a few sites I tried turing this into a prepared statement:

```
$db=new Database();
$query='SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_id`="'.$student_id.'" LIMIT 1';
$result=$db->query($query)or die('...');
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

As an "easy" first step, I tried using a prepared statement without any variables because I seem to be hopelessly stuck on a elementary level:

```
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "uname", "pword", "astro8_gakkou");
    if(!($stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_id`=5 LIMIT 1"))){
        echo "Prepare failed: (".$db->errno.") ".$db->error;
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed: (".$db->errno.") ".$db->error;
    }
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

This kills php in it's tracks. It's the last line that's the culprit, but I can't understand why. I know I'm just being dumb, but can someone point to what fundamental concept I'm missing? I've read through php.net along with a host of other sites and I just can't seem to see what step I'm missing.

UPDATE: still not working, but I've updated the code. The log shows this error now:

> [14-Mar-2014 22:34:10 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to
>   undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   /webdocs/zinc/class.Student.inc on line 38

Comment: Are you sure you can enter backquotes (`) in a query? As far as I know column names can be used without such quotes

Comment: If PHP itself crashes without giving any sort of error message, your code is not likely the culprit. Which makes this a good opportunity to switch to PDO instead of the fugly mysqli API.

Comment: There is not a single error message?

Comment: _“This kills php in it's tracks”_ – meaning what exactly? Please express yourself less prosaic, more technical.

Comment: Found the error, in the log... `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /webdocs/zinc/class.Student.inc on line 38`

Comment: @mario Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look at PDO later. One problem at a time.

Comment: You DON'T understand. PDO is not a "problem" but a SOLUTION to this problem.

Comment: PDO isn't a problem. Learning The syntax for PDO is. If I try updating all my code to use PDO and prepared statements, it'll be a hot mess. It's a lot easier to make one change and get it working from a troubleshooting perspective. That said, if anyone has a good link for prepared statements using PDO, I'd be greatful. The only examples I've seen use mysqli.

Comment: @YourCommonSense + mario. After crying about having to learn two whole things at once I did some internet and soul searching and figured it out in PDO. Thanks for the nudges!

Comment: Good to hear. For the real life PDO info read the tag wiki, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a 
   `$result = $stmt->get_result();`

Then pull the results
   `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Checkout the first user-contributed-note here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

The answer, despite my proclamations otherwise, was to use PDO. In it's simplest form this:

```
$db=new Database();
$query='SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_id`="'.$student_id.'" LIMIT 1';
$result=$db->query($query)or die('...');
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

Became this (using PDO and prepared statements):

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:dbname=school;host=localhost","root","root");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_id`= ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$student_id);
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetch();
```

**Huge thanks** to the folks that pushed me (yelling and screaming) to use PDO. This works wonderfully and doesn't throw a single error. It'll mean a bit more work updating the code, but I'm thinking it'll be worth it in the long run.

Comment: As a follow up. I found a [nice tutorial](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/) on creating a class using PDO. This should make my own transition a bit smoother.